# Outlook 2007 inbox message grouping like the Web App

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, outlook-web-access

The Outlook Web App has this nice, default, conversation grouping. It hides all earlier messages in a conversation from the message list. When I click a mail, it shows the conversation thread in the reading pane.

In Outlook 2007 I have tried grouping on received date, but it groups by minutes and not days. I've also tried grouping by conversation, but then I get this ugly tree in the list pane and I loose the "today", "yesterday", and vice versa groups.

**How do I make Outlook 2007 look like the Outlook Web App?**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should add a screenshot of the web app and your current setup

Comment: I am not sure on the correct answer, but I know a lot of people who swear by Xobni - see if this helps or at least fills in the missing gaps for you! - www.Xobni.com

Comment: I had a look at it and it didn't seem to solve my problem. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: I hope it makes sense.. MSPaint is fail without a blur option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Outlook Web App you are using is from Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. I didn't know that Outlook 2007 can connect to Exchange Server 2010. However, the functionality you are searching is part of Outlook 2010.

Comment: Aww, that's too bad. But yeah, it works like a charm, 2007 to 2010. I'm gonna accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this link](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/529) (summary provided below)

```
Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007
View-> Arrange By-> Custom-> button Other Settings…->enable option: Show items in Groups

Outlook 2010
tab View-> button View Settings-> button Other Settings…-> enable option: Show items in Groups
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [View messages by conversation or thread](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-messages-by-conversation-or-thread-HA001135667.aspx).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-messages-by-conversation-or-thread-HA001135667.asp

Comment: Hey Jamason, thanks for the reply. However, it doesn't give me what I want in the same sense the webapp does. I like the ability to view the whole thread (collapse and expand parts thereof) in the reading pane as opposed to the message list, like your example suggests.

Comment: Sorry I do not belive that feature is avilable in outlook 2007 or 2010.